# How to create html from json for 100 items without creating 100 single html files?

Tags: jquery, html, cordova, jquery-mobile, frontend

I develop an app with phonegap and jquery mobile.
I have 100 items and need single pages for it. The html is the same for all of them. It´s just displaying names and some information.
How can I parse 1 item to my html and display it with the information without creating 100 single html files? I have all the information as json.

EDIT: The user clicks on one of those 100 items and then the new page shall appear

Comment: Share an example of your JSON.

Comment: the json is something like this: {
  "boolean": true,
  "null": null,
  "number": 123,
  "object": {
    "a": "b",
    "c": "d",
    "e": "f"
  },
  "string": "Hello World"
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need a kind of templating, you can do it by yourself or use a consolidated approach. Just search the internet for "jQuery + template" and this will give you an idea of the many possibilities for such a task. You have REALLY a lot of ways to achieve what you need,

If you need interaction, two-way binding and a great SO community of supporters, IMHO knockout.js (or similar) is a good choiche, as already pointed out in a previous answer.

If you just only need to display data in a simple and straightforward manner, [nano](https://github.com/trix/nano) is the smallest template engine you could find, so, here is a simple JQM stub with two pages using this approach:

```js
var all = [], current = {};

var listTemplate = [
  '<li class="ui-first-child ui-last-child">',
  '<a href="#page-card" data-id="{id}" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r">',
  '<h2>{name}</h2>',
  '<p><strong>{address.city}</strong></p>',
  '<p>{email}</p>',
  '<p class="ui-li-aside">id: <strong>{id}</strong></p>',
  '</a>',
  '</li>'
].join("");

var cardTemplate = [
  '<h3 class="ui-bar ui-bar-a ui-corner-all">{name}</h3>',
  '<div class="ui-body ui-body-a ui-corner-all">',
  '<p>{email}</p>',
  '<p>{website}</p>',
  '<p>{phone}</p>',
  '<p>{address.street}</p>',
  '<p>{address.city}</p>',
  '</div>'
].join("");

function nano(template, data) {
  return template.replace(/\{([\w\.]*)\}/g, function(str, key) {
    var keys = key.split("."), v = data[keys.shift()];
    for (i = 0, l = keys.length; i < l; i++) { v = v[keys[i]]; }
    return (typeof v !== "undefined" && v !== null) ? v : "";
  });
}

$(document).on("vclick", "#page-list li>a", function() {
  var id = $(this).data("id");
  current = $.grep(all, function(item) {
    return item.id == id;
  })[0];
});

$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page-list", function() {
  var $ul = $(this).find("ul");
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users",
    method: 'GET',
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    complete: function() {
      $ul.listview().listview("refresh");
    },
    success: function(result) {
      all = result;
      $.each(all, function(i, item) {
        $ul.append(nano(listTemplate, item))
      });
    }
  });
});

$(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "#page-card", function() {
  $(this).find("[data-role=content]").empty().append(nano(cardTemplate, current)).trigger("updatelayout");
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div data-role="page" id="page-list">
    <div data-theme="a" data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
      <h3>Users</h3>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
      <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true">
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div data-role="page" id="page-card">
    <div data-theme="a" data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
      <h3>Details</h3>
      <a href="#" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn-left">Back</a>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Nice answer. @Klaxx note that if page's height exceeds 1000ish pixels, you lose animate transition. Try to paginate listview if you want to maintain animation.

Comment: Just one note: `pagebeforeshow` is deprecated. Use `pagecontainerbeforeshow`. However, it can't be attached to a specific page, hence, you can add a `.one()` time listener of `pagecontainerbforeshow` within `vclick` listener.

Comment: thank you @Omar for the notes! I will keep that in mind

Comment: @Omar can you please explain your last comment? I need to use .on('pagecontainerbeforeshow') within the vclick?

Comment: Thank you very much. Your solution works. However, when I copy the json file, https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users, to my Godaddy server. and updated the url in the JS portion of the code, it does not show the list or cards. What is wrong please?

Comment: @chikitin: How can I guess that? Write the URL of Your JSON file directly in the browser address bar. If You don't get it, then maybe You should refine the URL or configure Your server.

Comment: @Klaxx: Thank you for the reply. Here is the file: http://drsarami.com/dist/jsons/q_10_1_1.json.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider building it as a SPA using a simple binding library like KnockoutJS. This will allow you to update the data using a single page.

SPA Tutorial using Knockout (click the dropdown and select "Single Page Applications"):

http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=webmail

Download the library here: http://knockoutjs.com/

Of course you could use a robust framework like Angular, but that is really not necessary for just setting up some simple AJAX data bindings.