# JQuery Mobile reload Listview/html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

i recently started learning some web development and i am trying to create my first apache cordova app. It is supposed to download some json and show it in an unordered list (ul). I am using jquery mobile for styling. This is the code for writing json:

```
    var htmlString = "";
    htmlString += "<ul data-role=\"listview\">";
    htmlString += "<li>" + jsonData[0].name + "</li>";
    htmlString += "</ul>";

    document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = htmlString;
```

The styling works when i write it in index.html with data-role="listview", but when i write it in javascript it doesn't work, i think i need to somehow reload the page with jquery mobile. I couldn't find anything in the docs, probably because i don't exactly know what to look for.

Comment: no need to reload. Keywords here are: `listview("refresh")` and `updatelayout`. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43915438/4845566). BTW, to use JQM just only for styling is (IMHO) a common mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var htmlString = "";
htmlString += "<ul data-role=\"listview\ id=\"listViewUl\">";
htmlString += "<li>" + jsonData[0].name + "</li>";
htmlString += "</ul>";

document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = htmlString;
$('listViewUl').listview().listview("refresh");
```