# JQuery Mobile - How can I pass data context from a listview item to another page?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm generating a listview of "products" dynamically with some JSON data I'm getting using ajax request. When an user clicks on a item I want to take them to another page where all of the products details would be displayed.

```
$(document).delegate("#store", "pageinit", function() {
        getProducts('',
        function(data){
            let products = data.products;
            storeProducts(products);
            $(".product-list").html('');
            $.each(products, function(i, item){
              $(".product-list").append(`
                <li>
                  <a href="#product">
                    <img src="${item.picture}" alt="">
                    <h2>${item.prod_name}</h2>
                    <p>${item.prod_desc}</p>
                    <small>Price: <strong>€${item.unit_price}</strong></small>
                  </a>
                </li>
                `).listview("refresh");
            });

          },
          function(e){
            console.log(e);
          },
          function(data){
            console.log('always');
          });
    });
```

Now the problem is that I don't see how to pass the data context of a list item to another page (#product) in order to populate it with the corresponding information. I have seen a few approaches to similar use cases but they seem a bit ugly to me.

I believe this is a very basic feature for a web/mobile application nowadays; However JQuery Mobile doesn't seem to make it easy for a developer to implement such feature. Any plugin/library I can use to implement this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are creating the list items dynamically, this could be easily done by adding your own custom data attribute, like this:

```
'<li data-id="+${item.prod_id}+">'
```

Then, you can get the product context this way:

```
$(document).on("vclick", ".product-list li>a", function() {
  var id = $(this).data("id");
  ...get the product context by id
});
```

Here is an example with working demo: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43915438/4845566

BTW, just two small hints *aside* :

if you create the `html` token by using `[].join("")` you will avoid the extra spaces/tabs in markup.

You can also refresh the `listview` just one time, out of the products loop.