# New page link from user input ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, jquery-mobile

Im creating a bus finder application. I want the user to be redirected to a new page after they have input information for the ajax api request. At the moment the information is inserted after page one but on the same page. How do I create a new page with the ajax results once the user has inout the information and sent the request. I have a variable created with the results as a virtual page.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Dublin Concert Listings</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/theme.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<div data-role="page" id="pageone">

  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Get Next Bus Details</h1>
  </div>

      <div data-role="content">
        <div class="content-primary">
          <div data-demo-html="true">

            <div class="ui-input-search ui-shadow-inset ui-input-has-clear ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all">
              <input data-type="search" placeholder="Bus Stop Id" id="bus_stop_id" name="bus_stop_id">
            </div>

            <input type="button" value="Get Current Update" id="button_get_bus">

      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
 //On click of button this function get call
 $('#button_get_bus').click(function(){

 //Get Enter Bus Id
 var bus_stop_id = document.getElementById("bus_stop_id").value;
 //If Id is blank then given error
 if(bus_stop_id == "")
 {
  alert("Please enter bus stop number");
  return false;
 }

 //  This Function post request to API with the given bus stop id
  $.ajax({
     url: "https://data.smartdublin.ie/cgi-bin/rtpi/realtimebusinformation?stopid="+bus_stop_id+"&format=json",
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(results){

  // It returnes json data
  var str = JSON.stringify(results);  

  // Code for parsing json 
  var myObj = JSON.parse(str);

  var destination = myObj.results[0].destination;
  var origin = myObj.results[0].origin;
  var arrivaldatetime = myObj.results[0].arrivaldatetime; 
  var departuredatetime =     myObj.results[0].departuredatetime;
    var routenumber = myObj.results[0].route

    var virtualPage = "";

    virtualPage += 
    '<div data-role="page" data-theme="a" id="virtualPage">' 
    + '<div data-role="header">' 
    + '<h1>' + origin + '</h1>' 
    + '<div data-role="content">' 
    + '<h3>Venue: '  + destination + '</h3>' 
    + '<h3>Date: ' + arrivaldatetime + '</h3>' 
    + '<h3>Time: ' + departuredatetime + '</h3>' 
    + '</div' 
    + '<div class="wrapper"><a data-role="button" data-transition="slide" href="#pageone">Back</a></div>' 
    + '</div>'
    + '</div>';

     $(virtualPage).insertAfter($('#pageone'));

  }
       
  });
 });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Before AJAX request
[image: Before AJAX request]

After AJAX request
[image: After AJAX request]

Comment: don't create a new page at every search, use just one static page and then fill in dynamically the result from Your ajax request. Here is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43915438/4845566

Comment: I have filled a page dynamically but still results are on the same page code can be found here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50723180/linking-jquery-mobile-pages-one-with-user-input-and-another-with-results